# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] on object...android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have to compile a project purchased on line. On importing it into android studio..it complained about the gradle version so i updated the distributionUrl to this `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

When i now attempted to clean the project and rebuild..it failed with this error :

> Error:(45, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>    Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Below is the whole build gradle file :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

 android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "dumm.value"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.0.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }


  dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 

{

    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
/* Remove This to remove Crashlytics and Fabric */

  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
/*    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }*/
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please how can i solve this ?

Comment: post the code where you got the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use `implementation()` you need to use **gradle v.4** and the **gradle plugin v.3**

Use:

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

and

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }            
        //google()  //only if you use Android Studio 3.x
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'
    }
}
```

More [info here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

Comment: I still have same issue after doing this

Answer (score 3):

1.Open the build.gradle file for your application.
2.Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The repos are already in the build.gradle file...i have updated my question with these details above

Comment: And how can it solve the problem? The google maven is not related to the issue in the question.

Comment: where is the build.gradle folder?

Comment: @SeanMC its not a folder. its a file. Project level `build.gradle`

Comment: @NullPointerException Of course, I was referring to the folder containing it. My project only seems to have build.gradle files that are replaced everytime I build, so changing them makes no difference. Using Unreal Engine

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have found out that in app.gradle file

> implementationSdkVersion 27

was there instead of

> compileSdkVersion 27

so put it like below

```
 compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kotlinpractise"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still getting the error try changing android/build.gradle of your package in node_modules from implementation to compile. Worked for me.
You can use the following command inside your project folder.

```
sed -i -s "s#implementation#compile#" node_modules/your-react-native-package-name/android/build.gradle
```