# org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. Ive tryed the other posts and they didnt work

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Im having a big big trouble here . my app was running perfect and i needed to make the install release and things started to get a mess. Can you please check all the gradle code for more errors? ive followed a lot of stackoverflow post like: [Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] on object...android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619132/could-not-find-method-implementation-for-arguments-com-android-supportappcom)

also this one

[Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403444/could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-2-3)

The error is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key CapstoneUdacity from store "/Users/mac/Desktop/UdacityCapstoneFinalProject/app/release/release.keystore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:133)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:110)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt$onEach$1.invoke(_Sequences.kt:1260)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:148)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:108)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:132)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:152)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:633)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:663)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:654)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:140)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:115)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:32)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:393)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key CapstoneUdacity from store "/Users/mac/Desktop/UdacityCapstoneFinalProject/app/release/release.keystore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackagerBuilder.withSigning(IncrementalPackagerBuilder.java:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:646)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:496)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.lambda$doFullTaskAction$2(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:388)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key CapstoneUdacity from store "/Users/mac/Desktop/UdacityCapstoneFinalProject/app/release/release.keystore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.getCertificateInfo(KeystoreHelper.java:212)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackagerBuilder.withSigning(IncrementalPackagerBuilder.java:161)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.getCertificateInfo(KeystoreHelper.java:190)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 16 more
```

This is my code:

```
app build.Gradle

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {


    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'CapstoneUdacity'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storePassword 'password'
            storeFile file('/Users/mac/Desktop/UdacityCapstoneFinalProject/app/release/release.keystore.jks')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mac.udacitycapstonefinalproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth'
    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    })
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'CapstoneUdacity'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storePassword 'password'
            storeFile file('/Users/mac/Desktop/UdacityCapstoneFinalProject/app/release/release.keystore.jks')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mac.udacitycapstonefinalproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth'
    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    })
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

also:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also please check the error in detail there are more things about keystore.

Comment: Can you please check the password of the key store and the key alias. From error it seems that you have specified wrong password for the keystore or the key alias.