# How to find implementation() method in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

i want to add firebase database to my project ,when firebase in android firebase build automatic firebase dependency ,at the end this error happend:

> ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments
>   [com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>   build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edmt.dev.androidsimsimi"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
          'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//Add Library
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

}

Comment: Please include your build.gradle file.

Comment: How did you add the dependency? For a quick getring started go to tools/firebase and follow the assistant. That error seems to point Google Services is not added on the main gradle

Comment: i used firebase helper in android studio , after finish this error happend

Comment: Might be help, Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619132/could-not-find-method-implementation-for-arguments-com-android-supportappcom?rq=1

Comment: sorry it does not help @Dharma Kshetri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find method implementation() for arguments \[com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0\] on object...android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619132/could-not-find-method-implementation-for-arguments-com-android-supportappcom)